# What does SFINAE not work correctly with following has_member function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, sfinae

I'm trying out examples from [Walter Brown's TMP talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY) and I'm trying to get his `has_member` implementation working.

However the implementation seems to falsely return true which leads me to believe there is some detail of SFINAE that I am not understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class ...>
using void_t = void;

template <class, class = void>
struct has_type_member: std::false_type {};

template <class T> 
struct has_type_member<T, void_t<typename T::type> >: std::true_type {};

struct FooWithType
{
    typedef int type;
};

struct FooNoType 
{
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Does FooWithType have type member? " << 
        (has_type_member<FooWithType>() ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";

    std::cout << "Does FooNoType have type member? " << 
        (has_type_member<FooNoType>() ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n";

    return 1;                                                                                                                 
}
```

Output is:

```
Does FooWithType have type member? YES
Does FooNoType have type member? YES
```

I am on gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure your void_t implementation is fine? That's not how I remember it being implemented. Maybe it returns void even for ill-formed templates?

Comment: See [N3909](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3909.pdf), [N4436](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf) and [CWG 1558](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [C++11: SFINAE in template parameters, GCC vs Clang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28282398/)

Comment: Further duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25833356/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/26687062/

Comment: With g++5, it works as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that gcc 4.8.2 (and prior to gcc 5.0) does not regard unused arguments in alias templates as suitable for SFINAE.  The workaround is to forward to a `voider` class template:

```
template <class ... T> struct voider { using type = void; };
template <class ... T>
using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;
```

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911.pdf section 2.3:

> Alas, we have encountered implementation divergence (Clang vs. GCC) while working with the
>   above very simple definition. We (continue to) conjecture that this is because of CWG issue 1558:
>   “The treatment of unused arguments in an alias template specialization is not specified by the
>   current wording of 14.5.7 [temp.alias].”

Comment: @dyp right, unused default arguments. Took me a while to find the wording in Brown's paper.

Comment: Is that still true for the newer versions of GCC?

Comment: @KABoissonneault gcc 5.0 and above does not require the workaround.