# Template meta programming result changed between GCC-4.9.3 and GCC-5.1

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have a simple test program here which outputs a different result when compiling on `gcc-4.9.3` and `gcc-5.1`

```
#include <iostream>

template< class... >
using void_t = void;

template<class, class = void_t<>>
struct has_member_type : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T>
struct has_member_type<T, void_t<typename T::type>> : std::true_type
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_member_type<int>::value << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**`gcc-4.9.3` output:**

> ```
> 1
> ```

**`gcc-5.1` output:**

> ```
> 0
> ```

I've been unable to find an online compiler which allows me to compile with two different compiler versions.

However, I have found two separate online compilers which have difference compiler versions:

- Here is the [code compiled with `gcc-4.9.3`](http://rextester.com/OVEJ15498) (rextester)
- Here is the [code compiled with `gcc-5.1`](https://ideone.com/CZ6TkB) (ideone)

**Question:**

- Why does `gcc-4.9.3` output `1` when there is clearly no member `int::type`?

Comment: Yet another CWG1558 question...

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! >.< Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781523/what-does-sfinae-not-work-correctly-with-following-has-member-function